# Git do not overwrite symlinked directory on branch checkout

Tags: symlink, git

How can I make directory read-only with git?

The situation is - in project, I have a symlink to shared framework. I don't want it to be overwritten/changed in any way (not even mtime or atime).

How can I do that - or am I viewing the thing from wrong perspective?

Comment: A checkout usually does not touch untracked files in the working directory. Maybe I am missing your point.

Comment: Good point. But the files **have to be tracked**, because when I push them to let's say github, I want others to be able to pull them.

Comment: You want to have the symlink tracked or what it points to or both? You can't prevent people from changing files if they have commit access.

Answer (score 1):

For a specific directory, it is not possible (probably i am not right). For example, if user runs the following commands

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

or

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull
```

For details,

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/force-git-to-overwrite-local-files-on-pull
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720882/git-rebase-would-be-overwritten-and-no-changes-did-you-forget-to-use-git
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665045/can-i-tell-git-pull-to-overwrite-instead-of-merge

Git manual page may help you

- http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Answer (score 0):

First of all this question is probably more suited for [programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). And yes you are in my opinion viewing it from the wrong perspective.

It basically boils down to dependency management. You should just use the commonly used tools of your language/framework to express dependencies instead of copying/symlinking other projects.

If you really need/want to reference other git repositories you should use `git submodule` instead of requiring symlinks to other repositories.

The better and cleaner approach is to use the package-management of your distribution for the dependency management, `rpm` or `dpkg` or just let your build system or tools take care of the dependencies, like e.g.: `maven`, `bundler`, `carton`, `openembedded`.